# Can valueOf() return null according to Java conventions?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Is it acceptable to name a named constructor `valueOf` that may return `null` in some cases?

For example, `bar()` is a named constructor that may return `null` if the argument is `null`.

```
class Foo {
    public static Foo bar(String value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        else
            return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Would it be against the Java conventions to name it `valueOf()` instead? If not, I'm moving it to a helper.

**EDIT**: This method is a helper and must return null if the value is null for my needs.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "named constructor".

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I think he means factory method. But normally factory methods aren't named valueOf and take one parameter.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - One usage of the term "named constructor" to refer to factory methods rather than a language feature -- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.8

Comment: @Andy: Yes, it's clear what's being meant given the question - but the OP should be aware that this is not standard terminology.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: "Not standard terminology in Java community" better communicates that than "no such thing."

Comment: @Andy: Yes, possibly. "No such term defined in the Java language" would be another alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since that's not actually a constructor, you can do whatever you want with it. But you might want to think about throwing a `NullPointerException` instead of returning `null` if you are worried about your callers.

Comment: Actually, it has to return null for my needs.

Comment: Either way. Just make sure you Javadoc the function. If the function does what the documentation says, then you can't be wrong :-)

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with having a method like this return `null`, *granted that you explicitly* document the cases in which it will do so in the Javadoc summary so anyone who uses this method can understand when it will happen.

Also a slightly pedantic note: `bar()` is not a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In that case I would restrict the argument to be `null`. If it leads to `null` object to be returned, then it is wrong. So I would not bother my self with question can `valueOf()` return `null`.  I would use `IllegalArgumentException` or `NullPointerException` in case of null argument.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I vote for no. In my experience, `valueOf` methods throw exceptions when they don't know how to convert the input. An argument can be made for returning null if the input was null, but that's the only case I can see.

Answer (score 1):

As to me the best practice is to throw an `NPE` if the value is `null` and some other problem-oriented exception in case something else goes wrong. The main motivation behind that is that `null` is more for "unknown". I usually expect that `instanceof` test will return true when `valueOf` succeeded. This is not the case with `null`.